# Using DBT to create Join queries, but result omits some columns

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I have the following code that uses a right join to connect my data from Table 1 to Table 2. DBT compiled the code successfully without errors but I'm not getting the columns I need...

```
{{
  config(
    materialized='incremental'
  )
}}

with incremental_salesorder as (
  select * from {{ source('db_warehouse', 'sale_order_line') }} 
),

final as (
  select 
    distinct incremental_salesorder.product_code_cust, 
    incremental_salesorder.order_id as id,
    incremental_salesorder.create_date, 
    incremental_salesorder.name as product_name, 
    incremental_salesorder.product_name_cust, 
    sale_order.name as sale_order_ref
  from incremental_salesorder 
  right join {{ source('db_warehouse', 'sale_order')}} using (id)
  ORDER BY incremental_salesorder.create_date
)

{% if is_incremental() %}
  where incremental_salesorder.create_date >= (select max(create_date) from {{ this }} )

{% endif %}

select * from final
```

`incremental_salesorder.order_id` and `incremental_salesorder.name` are not in the results after the code compiled successfully

[image]

What am I doing wrong here... ?

Comment: Is it possible that you previously ran it without those columns and haven't re-run with the --full-refresh flag? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/run#refresh-incremental-models

Comment: @dylanbaker I solved it! I renamed the model, but did not update dbt_project.yml file with the new name, hence the entire query was not running at all, rookie mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rookie mistake:

Ensure that the defined model name is the same:

```
models:
    dbt_test:
      # Applies to all files under models/example/
        example:
            materialized: view
            +schema: staging
            +enabled: false
        sales_order_unique_incremental: <- this line must match the folder name
            materialized: table
            +schema: datastudio
```

[image]

I completely missed the warning. Once this was corrected I was able to compile the query and got the results I needed. In case anyone needs an example of how to do a join, this is a working method :)